# How to add multiple fields in Smartcapture form

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage

I am trying to have multiple field in my SmartCapture form as shown in the screenshot. I have duplicated the fields. I published this form, filled out all the fields. However, only the last field (lmp@xpm.com) [image]got inserted into the Data Extension.

Does anyone know why? Please let me know if you would require anymore info.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the page code or the data extension my guess would be because you have 3 fields all entering data into the same record in your data extension. So currently you have:

```
EMAIL > email
EMAIL > email 
EMAIL > email
```

And only the last value is being saved as the other 2 will be overwritten.

You will need to set up 3 separate fields that link to 3 separate records in your data extension so it looks more like:

```
EMAIL_1 > email_1
EMAIL_2 > email_2
EMAIL_3 > email_3
```

(and you will also need to do the same with the check boxes i assume)

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for the information. Yes, I understand your point. But what if I  do not know the number of entry fields. That is for one recipient I want to show only 1 email address field and for other I want to show 4 email address fields. So based on the recipient the number of input fields change.

Is it possible to use SmartCapture in this case?

Comment: To do this, you would have to set an upper limit for the amount of emails that can be captured, (10 for example) and then use some ampscript or similar to display however many email address fields you want to each user.  

It is hard to say without knowing the context for this page, but to be honest this doesn't seem like the most efficient way of capturing multiple addresses -
It would make more sense to have a single entry for every user and then give them the option to add another on your submit / thank you page if they wish.

Comment: One good news :) I have found out a solution using AmpScript and a second landing page. So I use the AmpScript to show varying number of fields (based on the recipient who exists in our Data Extension). Now once the Recipient submits this form (on the first landing page), I pass these options entered as Form data to the Second Landing page. I capture these values and insert them into a data extension from this Second Landing Page.

Answer (score 0):

With Smart Capture this is not possible. I guess the best solution is as @Aidan mentioned. But using manually coded form and AmpScript it is possible.